# RSpec reinterprets the action from index to show in view testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

I'm getting the following error for my index view:

```
  1) events/index.html.erb should display all the events in a matrix formation
     Failure/Error: render
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"events", :format=>nil, :id=>nil, :locale=>#<Event id: 2, name: "Miles Eichmann", description: "[\"Voluptas quia velit non est.\", \"Commodi aperiam p...", image: "event.jpg", location: nil, created_at: "2015-08-09 13:55:02", updated_at: "2015-08-09 13:55:02", whenwhen: "2015-09-07 04:00:00", speaker_id: 1, map_address: "800 Rene Levesque, Montreal, H3G 5K4", lon: 0.0, lat: 0.0, price: 3550>} missing required keys: [:id]
```

The test in spec/views/events/index.html.erb_spec.rb:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe "events/index.html.erb", :type => :view do
  let!(:speaker) { FactoryGirl.create(:speaker) }
  let!(:events) { FactoryGirl.create_list(:event, 10, speaker_id: speaker.id ) }

  it "should display all the events in a matrix" do
    assign(:events, events)
    render
    puts response
  end
end
```

I don't understand why if I have all the actions pointing to `index`, the error points to `:action=>"show"`.

If I delete the two `let` statements or take the `!` from them, the test passes and the headers and titles of the index page are displayed (with no events, of course).

The `index.html.erb` makes a call to helper functions to display the events in a matrix as follows:

```
<!-- app/views/events/index.html.erb -->
...
<% if Event.future.count == 0 %>
  <br><%= t(:staytuned) %>
<% else %>
  <h2><%= t(:futureevents).mb_chars.upcase %></h2>
  <%= raw(display_matrix_events(Event.future)) %>
<% end %>
...
```

which is one of the code segments that should be called, as the factory is creating events in the future:

```
#spec/facories/event.rb
require 'faker'

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :event do
    ....
    the_date { Faker::Date.forward(30) }
    ....
  end
end
```

The code works fine when running on the browser.

Here is the stack trace:

```
Failures:

  1) events/index.html.erb should display all the events in a matrix
     Failure/Error: render
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"events", :format=>nil, :id=>nil, :locale=>#<Event id: 1, name: "Columbus Goodwin", description: "[\"Quam est officia adipisci.\", \"Molestiae cumque vo...", image: "event.jpg", location: nil, created_at: "2015-08-09 20:22:27", updated_at: "2015-08-09 20:22:27", whenwhen: "2015-09-08 04:00:00", speaker_id: 1, map_address: "800 Rene Levesque, Montreal, H3G 5K4", lon: 0.0, lat: 0.0, price: 3550>} missing required keys: [:id]
     # /home/mancilla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/journey/formatter.rb:39:in `generate'
     # /home/mancilla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:595:in `generate'
     # /home/mancilla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:625:in `generate'
     # /home/mancilla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:661:in `url_for'
     # /home/mancilla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/url_for.rb:155:in `url_for'
     # /home/mancilla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_view/routing_url_for.rb:83:in `url_for'
     # /home/mancilla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/turbolinks-2.5.3/lib/turbolinks/xhr_url_for.rb:12:in `url_for_with_xhr_referer'
     # /home/mancilla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:228:in `call'
     # /home/mancilla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:268:in `block (2 levels) in define_url_helper'
     # /home/mancilla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/polymorphic_routes.rb:129:in `polymorphic_url'
     # /home/mancilla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/polymorphic_routes.rb:135:in `polymorphic_path'
     # /home/mancilla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_view/routing_url_for.rb:87:in `url_for'
     # /home/mancilla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/turbolinks-2.5.3/lib/turbolinks/xhr_url_for.rb:12:in `url_for_with_xhr_referer'
     # /home/mancilla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_view/helpers/url_helper.rb:180:in `link_to'
     # ./app/views/events/_speaker_in_event_index.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_events__speaker_in_event_index_html_erb__148285862205269253_56219800'
     # /home/mancilla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `block in render'
     # /home/mancilla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
     # /home/mancilla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
     # /home/mancilla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
     # /home/mancilla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_view/template.rb:141:in `render'
     # /home/mancilla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:306:in `render_partial'
     # /home/mancilla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:279:in `block in render'
     # /home/mancilla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
     # /home/mancilla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
     # /home/mancilla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
     # /home/mancilla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
     # /home/mancilla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
     # /home/mancilla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:278:in `render'
     # /home/mancilla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:47:in `render_partial'
     # /home/mancilla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:27:in `render'
     # /home/mancilla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_view/test_case.rb:198:in `render'
     # ./app/helpers/events_helper.rb:21:in `display_matrix_events'
     # ./app/views/events/index.html.erb:18:in `_app_views_events_index_html_erb__3520103631403717635_53363480'
     # /home/mancilla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `block in render'
     # /home/mancilla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
     # /home/mancilla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
     # /home/mancilla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
     # /home/mancilla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_view/template.rb:141:in `render'
     # /home/mancilla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:49:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
     # /home/mancilla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
     # /home/mancilla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
     # /home/mancilla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
     # /home/mancilla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
     # /home/mancilla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
     # /home/mancilla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:48:in `block in render_template'
     # /home/mancilla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:56:in `render_with_layout'
     # /home/mancilla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:47:in `render_template'
     # /home/mancilla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:17:in `render'
     # /home/mancilla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
     # /home/mancilla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
     # /home/mancilla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:24:in `render'
     # /home/mancilla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_view/test_case.rb:198:in `render'
     # /home/mancilla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_view/test_case.rb:118:in `render'
     # ./spec/views/events/index.html.erb_spec.rb:28:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 2.11 seconds (files took 3.79 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/views/events/index.html.erb_spec.rb:10 # events/index.html.erb should display all the events in a matrix formation
```

Comment: I am confused too, but I have notices a minor iisue with your test, you use instance variable `@assign` in expression `assign(:events, @events)`, but it must be `assign(:events, events)`

Comment: Does the index template (or its helpers) render any links?

Comment: @andrykonchin I made your suggested change in the code, but the error stays the same. I am editing the post now.

Comment: @zetetic yes, one of the helper functions do.

Comment: Can you add the stack trace from the failure?

Comment: @AaronK Adding to the the body of the post.

Comment: The stack trace shows it is failing in `url_for`. One of the links is being rendered with a `nil` value when it expects an integer (an ID), thus the message "No route matches... :id => nil"

Comment: @zetetic I found the line in question: `<%= link_to image_tag(e.speaker.image.to_s, width: '150%'), e %>`, `e` being the event object. If I change `e` to `e.id`, I get another error: `undefined method "model_name" for Fixnum:Class`. If I delete the line, the test passes. I do not know what is the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The action `index` is executed correctly but it has a sequence of `render`s and `method` calls which lead to a `show` action.

The `app/views/events/index.html.erb` file has a call to a method which renders a partial containing the line

```
<%= link_to image_tag(e.speaker.image.to_s, width: '150%'), e %>
```

RSpec interprets `e` in the `link_to` as is (i.e. an event object) instead of using its `id` to build the actual link as Rails does.

Changing `e` to `e.id` throws the error:

```
undefined method `model_name' for Fixnum:Class
```

in both the browser and RSpec.

Deleting this line make the tests pass, but of course, gives the wrong output.